# How to update custom reports in Dynamics 365 Field services

Tags: reporting-services, report, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We have a custom built SSRS Report that is been used on D365. When you navigate to the work order table in D365 and select a specific work order number a bar appears at the top of that page for the work order and one of the options is Reports. If you click on the drop down there are 2 custom built reports which you can run. I need to update that report and add columns but since I wasn't the one that created or published it I don't know how to display the report in that location.

Where do I publish the updated report to get it to display in this location. [location of custom reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASG6q.jpg)

I assumed that if I published the report to Powerapps it would link to D365 but after publishing it the new report doesn't appear on that list. We have managed and unmanaged folders with similar reports in Power Apps but I'm unable to replace the existing report in the managed folder.